# WordPress: Show only header on home page?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way to display only the header as the page, without the recent posts / static page in addition?

I did try to play around with it, but I always had to  choose between displaying recent posts or static page, and couldn't find a way to only display the header (and footer)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

.site-content {
display: none;
}